# How to get data from js websocket client in php websocket server after handshake?

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, handshake

I have a `nodejs` websocket client and a `php` websocket server. I need to get the data sent from the client after the connection is established... I'm not sure how to achieve this. Iv done a bit of research into the topic but couldn't find anything useful.

```js
// client.js

import WebSocket from 'ws';

let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
ws.on("open", () => {
    ws.send("Hello World"); // sending data after connection is opened
});
```

```php
// server.php

function newServer(string $address, int $port) {

    // Create WebSocket.
    $server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_option($server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
    socket_bind($server, $address, $port);
    socket_listen($server);
    $client = socket_accept($server);

    // Send WebSocket handshake headers.
    $request = socket_read($client, 5000);
    preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#', $request, $matches);
    $key = base64_encode(pack(
        'H*',
        sha1($matches[1] . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')
    ));
    $headers = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
    $headers .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
    $headers .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
    $headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
    $headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client, $headers, strlen($headers));

    // after handshake get data?
}

newServer("0.0.0.0", 8080);
```

Comment: You do `socket_read` in a loop on the server side or `socket_recv`, and if change is detected socket_accept the client, and then when the client side sends data, you have to unmask that data, then the data is all yours.